# Is there a way in C++ to preinitialize structure or class without a constructors?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, struct

I mean: I've a bunch of various structures/classes and all this a splendor shall be initialized with known in advance values. Those structures/classes will never be used other way except the preinitialized one, so there is no any need for constructor -- it's just a waste of extra memory, extra CPU cycles in program, and extra space in source code.

Comment: Will the values always be the same for all instances of a given class?

Comment: @juanchopanza, there should be only the one instance of a class. This is the reason, why I don't want a constructors.

Comment: A constructor will be created for you if you do not define one, so that "extra memory, CPU cycles, space" argument is invalid.  If you define no constructors, a default one is created for you by the compiler.  If you want to initialize values, you can use the proper constructor, or use an initialization list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structures and classes can be initialized, in limited circumstances.

```
struct splendor {
    int i, j;
    char *name;
};

splendor iforus = { 1, 2, "Extra!" };
```

Additionally, if you never need the name of the type of the structure:

```
struct {
    int k;
    float q;
} anon_e_mouse = { 1, 2.3 };
```

Comment: YOu could even do with an anonymous struct if that's enough.

Comment: I think this is the great idea, but compiler give an error if `splendor iforus = { 1, 2, "Extra!" };` somewhere global -- not in code.
Anyway, I think there is no other way, except paste it in code, right? I mean, in order to get it initialized in compile time.

Comment: Sorry, all right, it was my error -- I wrong wrote this. Thank you very much, it's okay. That's what I was seeked for.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to a C++11 compiler, you can mark your constructors as `constexpr` to have them run at compile time. The benefit of this is that way down the road you can still construct your objects at runtime. e.g.

```
struct Point2D {
    constexpr Point2D(int x, int y) : x_{x}, y_{y} {}
    int x_, y_;
};
```

And now you can use Point2D's constructor to initialize it at compile time, instead of runtime:

```
Point2D p{3, 4}; // no runtime overhead.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just initialize the members at the point of declaration:

```
struct Foo
{
  int i = 42;
  double x = 3.1416;
  std::string name = "John Doe";
};
```

This will set up the default values for all instances:

```
Foo f;
std::cout << f.i << std::endl; // prints 42
```

Note that this does not work with C++03, it requires C++11 support.

Comment: Note that this will work under C++11 only.  C++03 does not support this syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much, GCC understand C++11, I think I'll try this way too.

Answer (score 1):

If a class (or struct) doesn't have a constructor, you can initialize it like so:

```
MyClass a = MyClass();
```

or

```
MyClass * b = new MyClass();
```

This is called *value initialization* and it usually amounts to *zero-initialization*.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 gives you initializer_list.

```
#include <iostream>

struct s
{
    int i;  
};
int main() {
    s s1={666};
    s s2={42};
    std::cout<<s1.i<<" "<<s2.i<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can also do in-class initialization for member.

```
#include <iostream>
struct s
{
    int i=0;    
};
int main() {
    s s1; //s1.i = 0
    //s s2={42}; //fails
    std::cout<<s1.i<<" "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But you cant do bot at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to implement the Singleton Pattern.  When you do that, you still need a constructor (in fact, if you want to force it to be a singleton, you **have** to declare the default constructor as `private`).

```
class MySingleton
{
private:
    // my data

    MySingleton() { /* initialize my data */ }
public:
    static MySingleton& GetInstance()
    {
        static MySingleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    // other functions
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- I have never read about a _singleton_. It's interesting thing.

Comment: @YagamyLight  You can find more information about the Singleton Pattern here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.  Like any tool, it can be useful when used correctly, or painful when used incorrectly.